# How should I track the last active time of an user using graphql JWT?

Tags: django, jwt, graphene-python

I am logging user login information including OS, browser, ip, and device. And I want to delete it after 30 days of no activity period. The thing is my users use smartphones and they hardly re-login once they logged in. I overrided graphql_jwt.JSONWebTokenMutation like this:

```
class ObtainJSONWebToken(graphql_jwt.JSONWebTokenMutation):
    class Arguments:
        push_token = graphene.String()

    user = graphene.Field(UserType)

    @classmethod
    def resolve(cls, root, info, push_token=None, **kwargs):
        ip, is_routable = get_client_ip(info.context, ['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'REMOTE_ADDR'])
        ua_string = info.context.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
        user_agent = parse(ua_string)
        if user_agent.is_pc is True:
            device = 'Desktop'
        else:
            device = user_agent.device.family
        OS = user_agent.os.family + ' ' + user_agent.os.version_string
        browser = user_agent.browser.family + ' ' + user_agent.browser.version_string

        try:
            login_info = models.UserLoginInfo.objects.get(user=info.context.user, ip=ip, device=device,
                push_token=push_token, OS=OS, browser=browser)
            login_info.save()
        except models.UserLoginInfo.DoesNotExist:
            if push_token is not None:
                try:
                    duplicated_push_token_info = models.UserLoginInfo.objects.get(push_token=push_token)
                    duplicated_push_token_info.push_token = None
                    duplicated_push_token_info.save()
                except models.UserLoginInfo.DoesNotExist:
                    pass
            print(ip, device, OS, browser)
            login_info = models.UserLoginInfo(user=info.context.user, ip=ip, device=device,
                push_token=push_token, OS=OS, browser=browser)
            login_info.save()
        info.context.user.last_login = login_info.last_login
        info.context.user.save()

        return cls(user=info.context.user)
```

But I soon found a problem. The last login time only gets updated when users login, as I mentioned above. So I cannot delete UserLoginInfo past 30 days. So how should I update last active time of an user using graphql jwt?

I include a JWT token in Authorization header for every single request that requires authentication. And it is handled automatically by graphql_jwt. All I do is using @login_required decorator. But I want to override the resolver for @login_required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to update user's last active time is **middleware** because **every request made goes through it** so you can be confident that any activity is tracked.

E.g. overriding the `login_required` decorator would only affect endpoints where it is used and if multiple such decorated endpoints is used to resolve a graphql query every of them would access db to update a last active time so it would result in unnecessary server load.

Django last active middleware example:

```py
class UpdateLastActivityMiddleware(object):
   def __init__(self, get_response):
      self.get_response = get_response

   def __call__(self, request):
      if request.user.is_authenticated:
         User.objects.filter(pk=request.user.id) \
                     .update(last_activity=timezone.now())
      response = self.get_response(request)

      return response
```

Include it **after** authentication middleware:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'your_package.middleware.UpdateLastActivityMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

**Note:** it is not graphene middleware bacause it is called on **every field** resolution, but last activity should be updated once per request (that is exactly what django middleware provides).